# Jquery mobile google map - get direction example

Tags: jquery, cordova, google-maps

http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html#directions_map

Hi anyone know how to create a google map with the get direction feature just like the example above. However,the example above is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro). It returns multi-part directions for a series of waypoints. Directions for several modes of transportation are available.

For what you want to do, you're looking specifically in [waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints). Its as simple as calling the webservice with the 2 points you want go to and from. It will return you the list of the routes available and the legs of each route